# How can i get a json node from a specified level?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonpath

I have this json:

```
 {  
   "treeview":[  
      {  
         "text":"blah",
         "nodes":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "text":"blah",
         "nodes":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "text":"blah",
         "nodes":[  
            {  
               "text":"blah",
               "nodes":[  
                  {  
                     "text":"foo",
                     "nodes":[  
                         // I need to put data in here !!!
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "text":"blah",
         "nodes":[  

         ]
      },
      {  
         "text":"foo",
         "nodes":[  
             // Not here !
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to put value on "nodes" element where **i'm on level 2** and the **"text" equals "foo".**

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var json = myJson;
// First approach
var selector = (JArray)json.SelectTokens($"$..treeview[?(@.text == 'foo')]");
// Second approach
var selector2 = (JArray)json.SelectToken($"$.treeview[?(@...text == 'foo')]");

selector.Add(new JObject(new JProperty("text", "myValue"));
```

I don't understand how the "dot" in the query works... I just know that when you type 2 "dot" it browse the entire JSON... Is there a way to query a particular indent level only ?

Comment: You can deserialize it to class and take it, is this approach okay for you ?

Comment: No it's not okay, actually I generate this json and i need to put data on "nodes" element where i'm on level 2 and the "text" equals "foo"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out, yes we can specify a level indentation when we want to query a json in text plain, here's how:

```
var json = myJson;
var selector = (JArray)json.SelectTokens($"$.treeview[*].nodes[*].nodes[(@.text =='foo')].nodes");
selector.Add(new JObject(new JProperty("text", "myValue")));
```

**You can test it here:** http://jsonpath.com/

copy past my json sample in the json section and add this in the jsonPath: `$.treeview[*].nodes[*].nodes[*].text`

That's how you can get the `'foo'` value in the desired `"level of identation"` without specified any index in the arrays, just use this `'*'` instead of an `int`

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to work with objects than just plain json text...

using Newtonsoft.Json package...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var jsonstring = "{\"text\":\"blah\",\"nodes\":[{\"text\":\"foo\", \"nodes\": []}, {\"text\":\"bar\", \"nodes\": []}, {\"text\":\"foo\", \"nodes\": []}]}";

        //This is the root node
        var firstLevelNodes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Node>(jsonstring);

        //All the nodes in the root nodes node collection
        var secondLevelNodes = firstLevelNodes.nodes;

        //All of the nodes in the collections of the second level nodes
        var thirdLevelNodes = secondLevelNodes.SelectMany(sln => sln.nodes);


        Console.WriteLine("First Level Nodes: \n" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(firstLevelNodes).PrettyPrint());
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Second Level Nodes: \n" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(secondLevelNodes).PrettyPrint());
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Third Level Nodes: \n" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(thirdLevelNodes).PrettyPrint());

        secondLevelNodes.First().nodes = new List<Node> { new Node { text = "new node" , nodes = new List<Node>() } };

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Third Level Nodes (with new node): \n" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(thirdLevelNodes).PrettyPrint());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class JSONExtensions
{
    public static string PrettyPrint(this string json)
    {
        dynamic parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parsedJson, Formatting.Indented);
    }

}


[Serializable]
public class Node
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Node> nodes { get; set; }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
First Level Nodes:
{
  "text": "blah",
  "nodes": [
    {
      "text": "foo",
      "nodes": []
    },
    {
      "text": "bar",
      "nodes": []
    },
    {
      "text": "foo",
      "nodes": []
    }
  ]
}

Second Level Nodes:
[
  {
    "text": "foo",
    "nodes": []
  },
  {
    "text": "bar",
    "nodes": []
  },
  {
    "text": "foo",
    "nodes": []
  }
]

Third Level Nodes:
[]

Third Level Nodes (with new node):
[
  {
    "text": "new node",
    "nodes": []
  }
]
```

EDIT:

So if you only wanted the second level nodes that had the text foo just use..

```
var secondLevelFooNodes = secondLevelNodes.Where(sln=>sln.text == "foo");
//then use these nodes
```

EDIT2:

Using the your actual JSON object requires a TreeView Class as well...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var jsonstring = "{\"treeview\":[{\"text\":\"blah\",\"nodes\":[]},{\"text\":\"blah\",\"nodes\":[]},{\"text\":\"blah\",\"nodes\":[{\"text\":\"blah\",\"nodes\":[{\"text\":\"foo\",\"nodes\":[]}]}]},{\"text\":\"blah\",\"nodes\":[]},{\"text\":\"foo\",\"nodes\":[]}]}";

        //This is the root node
        var treeView = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TreeView>(jsonstring);

        //All the nodes in the root nodes node collection
        var firstLevelNodes = treeView.treeview;

        //All of the nodes in the collections of the first level nodes
        var secondLevelNodes = firstLevelNodes.SelectMany(fln => fln.nodes);

        //All of the nodes in the collections of the second level nodes
        var thirdLevelNodes = secondLevelNodes.SelectMany(sln => sln.nodes);

        Console.WriteLine("The TreeView: \n" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(treeView, Formatting.Indented));

        thirdLevelNodes.First(sln => sln.text == "foo").nodes = new List<Node> { new Node { text = "new node", nodes = new List<Node>() } };

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("The TreeView (with new node): \n" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(treeView, Formatting.Indented));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Node
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Node> nodes { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class TreeView
{
    public IEnumerable<Node> treeview { get; set; }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
The TreeView:
{
  "treeview": [
    {
      "text": "blah",
      "nodes": []
    },
    {
      "text": "blah",
      "nodes": []
    },
    {
      "text": "blah",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "text": "blah",
          "nodes": [
            {
              "text": "foo",
              "nodes": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "blah",
      "nodes": []
    },
    {
      "text": "foo",
      "nodes": []
    }
  ]
}

The TreeView (with new node):
{
  "treeview": [
    {
      "text": "blah",
      "nodes": []
    },
    {
      "text": "blah",
      "nodes": []
    },
    {
      "text": "blah",
      "nodes": [
        {
          "text": "blah",
          "nodes": [
            {
              "text": "foo",
              "nodes": [
                {
                  "text": "new node",
                  "nodes": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "text": "blah",
      "nodes": []
    },
    {
      "text": "foo",
      "nodes": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I agree, but what if I have multiple "foo" value in different nested level ? I just want "text" element on a particular level where "text" equals "foo", in your sample of code you browse all "n.text" where value equals "foo"

Comment: Nice approach, i'll try this !

Comment: I found a better way, see my answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the correct path to the "nodes" array. Try this:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse("{\"treeview\":[{\"text\":\"blah\",\"nodes\":[]},{\"text\":\"blah\",\"nodes\":[]},{\"text\":\"blah\",\"nodes\":[{\"text\":\"blah\",\"nodes\":[{\"text\":\"foo\",\"nodes\":[]}]}]},{\"text\":\"blah\",\"nodes\":[]},{\"text\":\"foo\",\"nodes\":[]}]}");
JArray array = (JArray)json.SelectToken("treeview[2].nodes[0].nodes[0].nodes");
array.Add(new JObject(new JProperty("text", "myValue")));
```

Comment: Sure but you specify an index here "treeview[2]" (2) actually, i don't know where it is...

Comment: If you don't where the specific node to which you want to insert data is, how are you going to find it...? You need to know the structure of your JSON data to be able to use a JSONPath to find a specific node.

Comment: Yes, i only know the level indentation, and i know there could be only one "text" value in this level

Comment: I found a way, see my answer